# embed some text at the point of the cursor in an html form

Tags: javascript, insert, cursor, textarea

Gvien a textarea tag, I can get the coordinates of the cursor using some javascript with onMouseDown when a user clicks there.  Now I want to be able to write some text to that point.  Is there any way to do that?
Thanks for you help,
Andynic

Comment: ah! cool.  Sounds like you need mouse position and an position:absolute element.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking can be difficult. I've found that the [code and tutorial here](http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/425/how-to-insert-text-into-a-textarea-where-the-cursor-is/) work very well. It will at least get you started.

Here's the code (if you don't want to follow the link):

```
function insertAtCaret(areaId,text) {
    var txtarea = document.getElementById(areaId);
    var scrollPos = txtarea.scrollTop;
    var strPos = 0;
    var br = ((txtarea.selectionStart || txtarea.selectionStart == '0') ? 
        "ff" : (document.selection ? "ie" : false ) );
    if (br == "ie") { 
        txtarea.focus();
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.moveStart ('character', -txtarea.value.length);
        strPos = range.text.length;
    }
    else if (br == "ff") strPos = txtarea.selectionStart;

    var front = (txtarea.value).substring(0,strPos);  
    var back = (txtarea.value).substring(strPos,txtarea.value.length); 
    txtarea.value=front+text+back;
    strPos = strPos + text.length;

    if (br == "ie") { 
        txtarea.focus();
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.moveStart ('character', -txtarea.value.length);
        range.moveStart ('character', strPos);
        range.moveEnd ('character', 0);
        range.select();
    }
    else if (br == "ff") {
        txtarea.selectionStart = strPos;
        txtarea.selectionEnd = strPos;
        txtarea.focus();
    }
    txtarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;
}
```